# Failed to parse service&apos

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, visual-studio-2017, python-3.6

Visual Studio 2017 Preview : Python workload : Python 3.6 : Anaconda3

I have:

```
import cx_Oracle as ax
import numpy as nm
import pandas as pd
```

All of these packages have been installed in Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages

When using Debug (F5) with a breakpoint on `import numpy as nm` - I step over that statement and all is well. However, when I step over `import pandas as pd` an error message pops up:

```
The debug adapter exited unexpectedly.
```

When I step into this statement the message is

```
Frame not in module - The current stack frame was not found in a loaded module.
```

When I view the disassembly, the message is `No disassembly available`.

The activity log error is:

```
Failed to parse service&apos;s registered package GUID ({BEB01DDF-9D2B-435B-A9E7-76557E2B6B52) for service {094e1961-17bf-4038-9bde-e7e11825c67b} as a GUID.
```

This issue also occurs on the `import matplotlib` statement.

I have looked on the internet for an answer to this issue but cannot find one.  I am very new to Visual Studio and to Python.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: To give some more information:  Windows 7 Enterprise - 64-bit :  Error message on Visual Studio pop-up - Cannot access a disposed object.  Object name:  'System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream'.

Comment: This issue also occurs in Visual Studio 2017 Professional